# Only prints last character in string

Tags: javascript, string, encryption

So I'm doing this challenge where I'm supposed to take this faulty encryption method and decrypt the message within 15 seconds. Okay I've built the program, it's very small, but it only gives me the the last character in the string. I understand why is because the variable sends x through the for loop processing the equation up to the last one. Then the next step comes from which it's converted from decimal to ascii and then displayed in a paragraph. I just cannot think of a way on how to do this for every character so the whole message is processed. It's not cheating on the challenge because I've technically have done the decrypting just can't figure this little thing out. It's completely legal and from hackthis.co.uk. I can't find anything on Google and have been trying everything I can think of. The only other idea in mind is to write out a huge array, which would be faulty and crash because the messages are randomly generated.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function decrypt() {
            var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
            var x = input.split(",");
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if (x[i].type = "text") {
                    crack = 94 - (x[i] - 32) + 32;
                    toTxt = String.fromCharCode(this, crack);
                    document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = toTxt;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea rows='4' cols='100' style='resize:none;' id='input'></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type='button' value='execute' onclick='decrypt()' />
    <p id='prompt'>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try: `document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML += toTxt;`, appending the latest `toTxt` value to the innerHTML, instead of replacing the whole thing

Comment: Note that your if statement is an assignment and not an equality operation (= vs ==). Also note that `x[i]` is of type [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) and doesn't have a [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype#Properties) named `type`. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish with that line.

Comment: === and == don't work only =

Comment: Plus === is to be used when equal to 0 and == when it's "equal to" something and = just equals

Comment: does anyone know how to get replace something specific in a string? for example I'm trying to get rid of ALL commas that area together. Keep single commas but get rid of two only.

Comment: "They don't work" is because strings don't have a `text` property. `x[i].type` is always `undefined` which is not equal to `"text"`. Your current expression is assigning `"text"` to `.type` which is then evaluated as `true` because a non-empty string is considered [truthy](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/). This means that it will always evaluate as `true` in which case you can just remove the if statement entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function decrypt() {
            var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
            var x = input.split(",");
            var txtDisp="";
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if (x[i].type == "text") {
                    crack = 94 - (x[i] - 32) + 32;
                    toTxt = String.fromCharCode(this, crack);
                    txtDisp=txtDisp+","+toTxt;

                }
            }
         document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = txtDisp;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea rows='4' cols='100' style='resize:none;' id='input'></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type='button' value='execute' onclick='decrypt()' />
    <p id='prompt'>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

concatenate all values derived from for loop in another string...
and then display it.

Comment: thank you for your help answered my question perfectly. The only problem I have left is trying to figured out how to put spaces between the words and have no commas between the characters. Some reason spaces are immediately removed in my code. Thank you though, I tried to up your thing but I need 15 reputations here